# Regular expression does not find a particular string

Tags: objective-c, regex, string

A weird problem with a regular expression.

The following regular expression

```
NSString* expression = @"^.*?(\bSKC|CLR|NSC|FEW|SCT|BKN|OVC|VV|CAVOK\b).*?$";
```

finds the string `BKN` in expression `BKN007` and `BKN007CLR002`, but does not find the String `CAVOK` in `110V270 CAVOK 03/M01`.

Can someone please help? Thanks!

P.S. The code is in Objective C but I do not think it matters as there is something wrong with the expression itself...

Comment: you need to better explain the context of what you're trying to match but i can tell you the issue is with `\b`. Based on what you *have* shown, I think you *probably* want this: `@"^.*?(\b(?:SKC|CLR|NSC|FEW|SCT|BKN|OVC|VV|CAVOK)).*?$"`

Comment: This is odd as it seems to match fine on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/qP4lE4)

Comment: Yeah, problem with \b. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably due to `\b` after `CAVOK` which means word boundary.

Try this regex:

```
NSString* expression = @"^.*?(SKC|CLR|NSC|FEW|SCT|BKN|OVC|VV|CAVOK).*$";
```

Comment: \b indeed! Saw it in some example and therefore originally put it there. Thank you so much!